# Problem with sql for a webpage built in C# by using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server

Me and my friend were trying to make a webpage in C#. 
This webpage has features like log in, log out and register.
So we tested it on his computer, and everything worked fine.

But then when I tried to test the code on my computer, I think the .sql file has some errors.

Some of them are:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have no idea if I am missing something like heading or setting. I searched in google and added "using System.Data.SqlClient;" to every aspx pages but nothing helped.

I hope you guys know what problem is this. Thank you.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using on your computer and your friend's computer? SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem looks to be that when you pasted it it replaced apostrophes with a different character that looks similar to apostrophes as well as double quotes with a similar character, this sometimes happens when you copy and paste from somewhere. 
Go into sql and do a find and replace (ctrl + H) in the script by copying the incorrect character to clipboard and replacing it with the correct character.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to run this against a MS SQL Server, you're going to have problems.  That syntax is MySQL.  The give away for me is "ENGINE=MyISAM", but there are other constructs in there that T-SQL (the language that is used to run commands against SQL Server) don't have.  You'll have to get rid of those (or convert them) in order to accomplish what you're trying to do.